# consultar fecha en sql server con en numero de la semana y el numero del dia de la semana

Tags: sql, sql-server

hola compañero tengo un pequeño inconveniente.

-tengo un año.

```
declare @anio varchar(50)
set @anio = '2019'
```

-tengo un mes.

```
declare @anio varchar(50)
set @anio = '01'
```

pero no tengo el día solo tengo el numero de la semana, y el numero del dia en la semana.

```
declare @Semana varchar(50)
declare @Dia varchar(50)

set @Semana = '2'
set @Dia = '3' de la semana.
```

como se que día es exactamente.
necesito calcularlo en sqlServer.
¿me pueden ayudar?

Comment: Lo tienes.... dónde? En una columna d ela BD?En un texto? Cómo obtienes el número de la semana y del día en la semana?

Comment: en variables, ya edite la pregunta

Comment: ¿Lo que tienes es el número de semana del mes o el número de semana del año?

Comment: del mes compañero

Comment: cómo se define cuál es la primera semana de un mes?

Comment: ¿en qué versión de SQL Server estás trabajando?

Answer (score 1):

Segun lo que entiendo de tu pregunta se me ocurre que deseas hacer lo siguiente

```
declare @anio varchar(50)
set @anio = '2019'
declare @mes varchar(50)
set @mes = '01' 
declare @Semana varchar(50)
declare @Dia varchar(50)

set @Semana = '2'
set @Dia = '3' 

select dateadd(day,convert(int,@Dia)-1,dateadd(week,convert(int,@Semana),concat(@anio,'-',@mes,'-01')))
```

El -1 que pongo en el primer dateadd es para restar un dia que ya estoy agregando al final del segundo dateadd en el concat

Answer (score 0):

La mejor opción es crear una tabla de calendario con las columnas necesarias.

```
CREATE TABLE Calendario(
    fecha           date,
    Año             int,
    Mes             int,
    SemanaMes       int,
    SemanaAño       int,
    DiaSemana       int,
    NombreDiaSemana varchar(10),
    EsInhabil       bit);
```

Lo llenas una vez y puedes consultar de ahí según los parámetros que necesites. Agrega tantas columnas como necesites para los cálculos dependiendo de los requerimientos del negocio.

En tu caso obtendrías la fecha como

```
DECLARE @anio int,
        @mes int,
        @Semana int,
        @Dia int;
SELECT  @anio = 2019,
        @mes = 1,
        @Semana = 2,
        @Dia = 3;

SELECT fecha
FROM Calendario
WHERE Año       = @Anio
AND   Mes       = @mes
AND   SemanaMes = @Semana
AND   DiaSemana = @Dia;
```